# Python : how to split sentences in two sentences properly?

Tags: python

I have a string in big_sentence variable.

big_sentence = "1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.2.Lorem ipsum ....... dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

I would like to have a split like this:

> var_1 = "1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
> eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
> minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
> aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
> reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
> pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
> culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
>
> var_2 = "2.Lorem ipsum ....... dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
> sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
> enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
> ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
> reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
> pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
> culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

I tried to do this:

```
big_string.split('.')
```

But the problem in big_sentence is that I have "1." "2." and also part with several periods "....." after "2.Lorem ipsum"

How can I do to achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likekly can achieve that what you want using a regex. eg.

```py
import re

split_sentences = re.split('(\d\.)', big_sentence) # \d matches any digit \. matches any '.' and the () will include the match in the output
filter_split_sentences = list(filter(None, split_sentences)) # filter empty ones
var_1 = ''.join(filter_split_sentences[0::1]) # take first two of list using slicing
var_2 = ''.join(filter_split_sentences[2::1]) # take second two of list using slicing
print(var_1)
print(var_2)
```

Will output:

```py
>>> print(var_1)
1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.2.Lorem ipsum ....... dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
>>> print(var_2)
2.Lorem ipsum ....... dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the regex. Something similar to this.

```
import re

re.split("\d\.", big_sentence). # \d means a digit and \. means a dot

['',
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
'Lorem ipsum ....... dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.']
```

Comment: Your result sentences don't contain the numbers. Plus there's an additional empty sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if it won't always be the case, but in this case, there is a `2.` dictating where it could be split, so you could do something like this:

```py
big_string = "1.xxx.xxx.2.yyy.yyy."
var_1 = big_string[:big_string.find("2.")]
var_2 = big_string[big_string.find("2.")+2:]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try havin the 2 sentences separated by a new line, so:

`big_sentence = "sentence 1\nsentence 2"`

`big_sentence.split(\n)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to split on an empty string followed by a number-period pattern (this will keep the numbers in the resulting sentences).

```
import re

_, var_1, var_2 = re.split(r"(?=\d+\.)",big_sentence,2)
```

output:

```
print(var_1)
```

1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

```
print(var_2)
```

2.Lorem ipsum ....... dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Typically, you would want to assign the sentences to a list variable rather than individual string variables.  This will allow for more than two sentences and will automatically adjust to the number of sentences in `big_sentence`:

```
_,*sentences = re.split(r"(?=\d+\.)",big_sentence)
```

output:

```
print(len(sentences))
```

2

```
print(sentences[0])
```

1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

```
print(sentences[1])
```

2.Lorem ipsum ....... dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.